# flutter sign in application does not sign out in android emulator

Tags: flutter, google-signin

I am implemeneting the sign in part of my application, I have followed this documentation.
https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase-auth-in-flutter-apps#6
Of course I have followed and checked three times the instruction.
For the web application everything is working perfectly, for iOS and Android not.

Here I ask only for Android.
Problem 1. Once Signed in with Firebase I am not able to sign out
Problem 2. Clicking on "Sign in with Google" I receive an unknow error occured,

I have found plenty of the same problem but the solutions does not fix my problem

if I comment the line with the GoogleProvider definition the SignOut is working perfectly.

Someone experience the same?

Thanks

Try to Sign in and Sign Out from the application

Comment: can you add more details for error what view in terminal

Comment: I have found that it is an emulator problem, I will provide more information in the next days.
In the meantime I have in any case distribute a test application as it is in a real Android phone and it works perfectly.
Not tested yet in iOS.
This is clearly an emulator problem